# Detect if network has changed?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How do I know if the device has changed its network? For example with this use case:

1. User connects to Wi-Fi A.
2. User starts my app.
3. User connects to Wi-Fi B. (or even 3G)
4. User restores app.

Is there anyway to notify the app, that the device changed from Wi-Fi A to Wi-Fi B?

Comment: I might've not been specific with my question enough. So I'll the specifics in here. I keep my XMPP socket connection alive in the background, I don't disconnect it so I when the app is brought back to the foreground, I can just use that again, and no reconnection necessary. Now when the user changes network, like Wi-Fi A to Wi-Fi B, the socket connection is now invalid. When the app is in background, Reachability notifications doesn't work. There is no background execution in my app, so I guess, Reachability isn't really the answer for this.

Comment: The solution I found for this is by using the BSSID of the network, and save it when I put the app in background, then when I put the app in foreground, I check the current BSSID, and if it's not the same, I renew the socket connection.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice drop in alternative that is ARC compatible
https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Answer (score 0):

[Use Reachability in your Project Fetch the Networks Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

The SCNetworkReachability interface can help you with that. Basically, you create a so-called reachability reference and then call SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags on it to get information about the connection.